# Cron expression validator

Tags: c#, cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, schedule

I would like to have user-defined cron expressions in my program. Are there are validators for cron expressions so that the user cannot insert an invalid cron code?

**N.B.** I think the cron expression on Quartz.Net has a slight different format than the one used in UNIX. I would like to the Quartz version of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UNIX Cron expressions and Quartz ones are differents. Simply,

- In Unix

  - (minute, hour, day, month, day_of_week, year)
- In Quartz

  - (second, minute, hour, day, month, day_of_week, year)

You can use [this](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/) to know if a Cron expression is correct.

EDIT : Look at `CronExpression.ValidateExpression` method.

Comment: which function on the API page you linked can I use to say if my cron is correct?

Comment: Just to add to this answer, we can use CronExpression.IsValidExpression(string expression) if you're looking to make decisions based off of that call.

Answer (score 2):

The question is aged but now there are more options.

I found useful this new nuget package [NCrontab.Advanced](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NCrontab.Advanced/) that is a good replacement for the older [NCrontab](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ncrontab/) adding more features, and should have a more wide range of application.

Answer (score 2):

Can use The method CronExpression.IsValidateExpression() with an additional regex validation using regex.

example

```
public static bool IsValidSchedule(string schedule) {

        var valid = CronExpression.IsValidExpression(schedule);
        // Some expressions are parsed as valid by the above method but they are not valid, like "* * * ? * *&54".
        //In order to avoid such invalid expressions an additional check is required, that is done using the below regex.

        var regex = @"^\s*($|#|\w+\s*=|(\?|\*|(?:[0-5]?\d)(?:(?:-|\/|\,)(?:[0-5]?\d))?(?:,(?:[0-5]?\d)(?:(?:-|\/|\,)(?:[0-5]?\d))?)*)\s+(\?|\*|(?:[0-5]?\d)(?:(?:-|\/|\,)(?:[0-5]?\d))?(?:,(?:[0-5]?\d)(?:(?:-|\/|\,)(?:[0-5]?\d))?)*)\s+(\?|\*|(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3])(?:(?:-|\/|\,)(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3]))?(?:,(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3])(?:(?:-|\/|\,)(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3]))?)*)\s+(\?|\*|(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(?:(?:-|\/|\,)(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))?(?:,(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(?:(?:-|\/|\,)(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))?)*)\s+(\?|\*|(?:[1-9]|1[012])(?:(?:-|\/|\,)(?:[1-9]|1[012]))?(?:L|W)?(?:,(?:[1-9]|1[012])(?:(?:-|\/|\,)(?:[1-9]|1[012]))?(?:L|W)?)*|\?|\*|(?:JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)(?:(?:-)(?:JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC))?(?:,(?:JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)(?:(?:-)(?:JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC))?)*)\s+(\?|\*|(?:[0-6])(?:(?:-|\/|\,|#)(?:[0-6]))?(?:L)?(?:,(?:[0-6])(?:(?:-|\/|\,|#)(?:[0-6]))?(?:L)?)*|\?|\*|(?:MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN)(?:(?:-)(?:MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN))?(?:,(?:MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN)(?:(?:-)(?:MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN))?)*)(|\s)+(\?|\*|(?:|\d{4})(?:(?:-|\/|\,)(?:|\d{4}))?(?:,(?:|\d{4})(?:(?:-|\/|\,)(?:|\d{4}))?)*))$";

        return valid&& Regex.IsMatch(schedule, regex);
    }
```